# Best way to create Default.png image for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Originally I though I'll just take a screenshot of my app on the iPhone then tweak it in  Photoshop.

The images should be 480 x 320 according to [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW20), and the dimensions of my screenshot are 480 x 320. But, the screenshot contains notification area (where reception bars, battery life, etc. are displayed)

So, if I chop that part off my image will be a bit shorter and not 480px high.

What do I do? Submit a shorter image? Stretch it up so it's 480px but without the notification bar? Submit it with the notification bar in the image?

How did you create your Default.png?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can leave the notification area in the screenshot. The iPhone will draw the real notification bar over it.

**iOS 7 update**: the [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Scoping.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH7-SW1)  explicitly requires this:

> Update the launch image to include the status bar area if it doesn’t already do so.

Comment: Or black it out if it bothers you.

Comment: The problem with a screenshot now though is that the live status bar gets drawn on top of the old status bar in the screenshot - resulting in an ugly mess. Is there a better answer for iOS 7?

Answer (score 53):

There is support in Xcode for creating the default image. With the device connected, open the Organizer (Window > Organizer). Click the Screenshot tab, take a screenshot and click "Save as default image..." Choose your project and bingo jingo, you're done.

Comment: "Bingo jingo" LOL I'm stealing the hell out of that.

Comment: Not upvoting just because I'd like the number to stay at 42 :p

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to do it is to use the Xcode screenshotter & edit some of the GUI elements out, like the artwork or text on your buttons so people don't get frustrated when pushing 'buttons' on the Default.png doesn't make your app respond.

Comment: I second this. Load up a picture of an "empty" UI, this makes it look like your app is halfway loaded, but you still can't interact with it. It shows some progress of the load, too.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a status bar, then you should design 320x460 (less 20 pixels).

Though it is correct that you can leave it at 320x480 and have the real status bar paint over the default.png, it will look weird when the phone is in Internet tethering mode or has a call on hold (another 20 pixels).

By cropping to 320x460, it looks better when in tethering mode.

Comment: Great tip! Everyone with a status bar should use 320x460. In tethering mode it automatically chops a bit out of the middle, so the top and bottom bars match perfectly!  Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Just edit out the notification area to match the background of the rest of the image.  As long as your image is 480x320 you should be fine.

However, if your app takes more than a few seconds to load, you may want to rethink using a screenshot of your app as the startup screen.  People might get confused and think the app is finished loading, when in fact it is not.  I've seen some apps produce a "stylized" version of their UI in Photoshop, making it clear that it's just an image and not the actual UI.

Answer (score 2):

you should remember that you maybe need also some space for an In-Call status bar or the Tethering status bar. this bar has a height of 20 pixels. Even apple does not make it right. Put a call on hold and start "Photos" or the "Weather" app, then you can see what I mean. To test that you can use the menu "Toggle In-Call Status Bar" in the iPhone Simulator app.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a real 480x320 image if you add the boolean key UIStatusBarHidden to your Info.plist file and set it as true.

Answer (score 2):

Take a screen shot as many of the answers already mention. However, if your screen shot includes the status bar, you should remove it/replace it with a transparent strip instead. It is true that the iPhone will cover this part of Default.png with the current status bar however, if you run the iPhone app on the iPad, you will still be able to see this part of Default.png.

Answer (score 1):

I built a slightly modified version of the initial view in IB, ran the app with that and took a screen shot. That way, everything looks very iPhoney, no Photoshop needed. Don't worry too much about clipping the top, it will mirror how the view actually looks when loaded if more stuff covers it.

Apple recommends something *similar* to what the user will see when the app loads. E.g. for my Sudoku app, instead of the grid, the default.png shows a "please wait" message. When the app is loaded, that disappears and you see the grid you can interact with. It looks fluid, and it's obvious when it's loading and when you can interact.

Finally, the interface uses some toolbar buttons. In the default.png they are in the disabled state (grey text). When the app is loaded, they are enabled and change color.