# iOS Default.png status bar not drawn over

Tags: iphone, ios

This is probably something simple but I'm having a problem with my Default.png file.  I created it using the XCode organizer to take a screenshot and having it assign it as the Default image.  According to this post ([Best way to create Default.png image for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493433/best-way-to-create-default-png-image-for-iphone-app)) iOS is supposed to draw the real status bar over top of the status bar in my Default.png but that's not happening; it shows two status bars stacked on top of each other until the app completely loads and everything is normal.  This is distracting and obviously looks like crap.

I've tried hiding the status bar during startup and reenabling it during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but the status bar in my Default.png is still at the top.

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the XCode screenshot tool takes a screenshot that's conveniently just a little too tall, making it safe to trim off the top.  I cut the status bar out of the picture using Seashore and it's all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Default.png 320 x 480 pixels in size?  (You can use the Inspector in Preview to show the size.)