# iOS launch image status bar showing over system status bar

Tags: ios, statusbar

I'm having an issue where it seems the status bar in my launch image is simply getting shown over the system status bar rather than getting cropped out. This results in a nasty jumbled look while the app launches (see below).

[image: launch image overlay problem]

It's even worse on an actual device as the Carrier and battery icon are also overlaid.

This is the same issue as [iOS Default.png status bar not drawn over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739333/ios-default-png-status-bar-not-drawn-over); however, Xcode won't let me apply a launch image with the status bar cropped out as it's too small.

My images are all the correct size. I created them by saving screenshots from the iOS simulator. I wouldn't mind hiding the status bar during launch but this just shows the static status bar from the launch image.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem here? Just erase the status bar from you launch image.

Comment: As stated before if I remove the top 20px from the image Xcode throws a warning that the image isn't the right size.

Comment: I had a similar problem, except that my launch image was painting over the entire status bar. Turns out the problem was that the status bar style was set to "light" under Deployment Info; setting it back to Default fixed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't replicate the status bar in your launch image, I assume you are using a simulator screenshot as your launch screen.

To overcome that, open that screenshot in a photo editing app (as PhotoShop), and hide the status bar with a layer having its background color.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I was hoping there was an easier way (as I have images for iPad and iPhone across several versions) but this is what I ended up doing. The Apple guidelines and a number of other questions on SO seem to suggest the top 20px from the launch image shouldn't be visible, but I guess this has changed or isn't the case here.

Answer (score -2):

I FOUD THE SOLUTION ! Just add the source "http://repo.hackyouriphone.org" and then install the package "statusbarfix2" next you make a respring and everythings is good! it worked on 4, 4s, 5 and 5s :)